# 'MyEnum' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift

I have a enum with raw values in a class in my framework which I want to use with another class. I'm getting the following error.

```
'types' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
```

From this line...

```
var table = sdb?.getTable(LoggerStartup.eTables.types)
```

Here's my enum from my framework

```
public class LoggerStartup : NSObject
{
    public enum eTables
    {
        static let users    = 100
        static let types    = 200
        static let items    = 300
        static let measures = 400
    }
}
```

From what I've seen, I'm not sure if I can have raw values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `static` properties are still `internal` by default, you have to declare them `public` too:

```
public class LoggerStartup : NSObject
{
    public enum eTables
    {
        public static let users    = 100
        public static let types    = 200
        public static let items    = 300
        public static let measures = 400
    }
}
```

Of course, this would be different, if you used an actual enum:

```
public enum eTables: Int {
    case users = 100
    case types = 200
    case items = 300
    case measures = 400
}
```

In that case you would be able to use `eTables.types` directly.